# How to store and retrieve images dynamically in MERN application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

everyone! I'm writing my application using a mern.io boilerplate. I encountered the following problem: suppose that in the same model of the post I want to store also a picture, which way is the best to do it and how to deliver the image pictures embedded in the 'post' document in mongo? I thought that I can simply store images in the folder 'public' and add something like 'imgUrl' field with the path to corresponding picture in mongo documents. So, I tried to add a folder with pictures and add a line `app.use(Express.static (path.resolve (__ dirname, '../public')));` in server.js, but it didn't work, i can't retrieve any picture from public. What should I do in this case? Is it necessary to add something in a webpack configuration? I understood how the picture in the header is displayed, but what if I want the path to the picture to be set dynamically from the database?

Comment: https://github.com/shabyWoks/shabywoks/blob/master/src/components/Dashboard.js

Comment: i have used images in the above link and saved it to public folder.. images are static